# Migrating SharePoint 2007 to servers on a new domain

Tags: 2007, migration, windows-server-2008-r2, database-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 Moss 2007 SP3 (32 bit) servers on Server 2003 R2 (32 bit) that I would like to move to server 2008 r2 (64 bit) servers.

There is one database server that will be upgraded to Server 2008 R2.  The SQL Server version will also be 2008 R2.

In this scenario, what would be the recommended approach to migrate Moss 2007 to these new 2008 R2 servers?  Am I going to run into any compatibility issues with the new 64 bit servers?

The other catch is that the new 2008 R2 servers and database server will be on a new domain.

Answer (score 0):

just do a content database migration. detach/attach method.

going from 32 to 64 isnt going to be an issue. Its an issue when you want to go from SQL 2012 to SQL 2008. But in your case that isnt the issue.

look at this as a guide:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303420%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

in your case going from 2007 to 2013 is the issue. You cant go directly so you would need to goto 2010 and then to 2013 unfortunately.

wrote this ages ago 2003/2007 to 2010.... but with the guide above its pretty much the same from 2010 to 2013

[attach content db to SharePoint Server 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66290/attach-content-db-to-sharepoint-server-2010)

Comment: thanks for that answer.  What about the new servers being on a different domain?  Any issues there?  What about any solutions that are running on the 32 bit server?  Will they work on the 64 bit server?

Comment: SharePoint will remain 2007 32 bit on the new server 2008 R2 servers..

Comment: solutions on 32 moving over to 64 shouldnt be an issue. what would be an issue is if you move 64 to 32. being that its on a different domain would have no effect when doing a content database migration as the web application is created on the domain.